# Accessing Ximea API via OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, ximea

OpenCV has a great support for XIMEA cameras. However, I cannot find a way to access the XIMEA-specific functions and key words. I found on other sites (and on Stackoverflow), that there are key words like `CV_CAP_XIAPI` or `CV_CAP_PROP_XI_DOWNSAMPLING`, but I can't find them in Python.

In detail, the cameras have an auto-exposure feature and I would like to deactivate that. If I set the `CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE` to a specific value, it changes, however, after a couple of (milli)seconds, the auto-exposure takes over again. Is there a way to force the camera to stick to that value?

Thank you for your help.

Best,
anki

Btw, there's a direct XIMEA Python binding called [pyximea](https://github.com/pupil-labs/pyximea), but I haven't solved building it on Windows yet, so, I rely on OpenCV (which is great and would be even better when I could directly access the API).

Comment: I can see those methods in OpenCV 3.0 by doing `import cv2` and `cv2.CV_CAP_XIAPI`

Comment: Ok, I am having 2.4.11, probably it's worth installing cv3 then ;)

Comment: Might be worth trying `from cv2 import cv` and see if you can see them in `cv`

Comment: I already did this, but haven't found it. Now I probably have to change to Python 3.x because OpenCV 3 would love to see Python 3...

Comment: I'm using OpenCV 3 with python 2.7; you don't need to switch to python 3

Comment: Ok, then I'm trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined by Ryan, the OpenCV version is crucial. Building OpenCV 3.0.0 from Source including the option `WITH_XIMEA` for Python 2.7.x works perfect. I offer a [downloadable compiled package on my blog](http://anki.xyz/ximea-opencv-3/). Thanks!

Comment: A short update: I switched now to Python 3.5.x, works beautifully with OpenCV 3.1. And vice versa, OpenCV 3.1 with Python 2.7.x.